# How to graphically throw a ball into a hoop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm having a Python3 class in university and am supposed to do a final project including solving ODEs. My idea is to solve for the elliptic curve of a basketball and do a little game with that, where the user gives initial velocity and angle and tries to hit the hoop.

While the mathematical path is completely finished I'm having problems with the GUI part. I'm coming from VBA so I don't know a lot about Python and PyQt5 except from what we had in the course. My basic idea was to have a painting area with two pixmaps on it, one for the ball and one for the hoop. Then I wanted to move the ball along the curve which was solved for the given velocity/angle.

In VBA I could just create two image-controls on a UserForm and move on of them in a loop with a slight pause between each step so is there something similar in PyQt5?

I'm really only looking for hints on how to do that and of course I did some research [about QPropertyAnimation](http://zetcode.com/pyqt/qpropertyanimation/) for example. But I can't even manage to find hints on how to show two independent pixmaps in the same scene (which would be pretty much the solution to my problem I think).

Comment: This could be simpler for you to use [pygame](https://www.pygame.org/news) than PyQt5

Comment: I'll have a look into it, thanks a lot!